# Zend Framework captcha, Strange Character

Tags: php, zend-framework, captcha

Captcha is generating these kind of characters in Zend Framework: ä, ë, etc. I am trying but I don't know how to avoid them, I just want a-z letters and numbers.

Thank you.

Comment: Which Zend Captcha adapter are you using and what is the version of Zend Framework?

Comment: I am using Zend Framework 1.12, I dont know what version of captcha is, but it use this code to create it:  $this->captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha(
                        'captcha' ,
                        array(
                            'captcha' => $this->_captcha
                            
                        )
                );

Comment: How do you form variable  `$this->_captcha`?

Comment: It is inherit, and is:
$this->_captcha =
    array( 'captcha' => 'Image' ,
     'wordLen' => 4 ,
     'timeout' => 300 ,
     'width' => 120 ,
     'height' => 50 ,
     'height' => 50 ,
     'DotNoiseLevel' => 5 ,
     'LineNoiseLevel' => 2 ,
     'font' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/font/IMPACTED.TTF' ,
     'imgDir' => APPLICATION_PUBLIC . DS . 'captcha' . DS ,
     'imgUrl' => '/captcha/' , ) ;